# Amazon Web Services -- Appium TestNG integration

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, testng, appium

I'm new to Amazon Web Services and I want to use Amazon Web Services'(AWS) device farm to run an Appium-automated-test against my built application. However, while automated testing using Appium and my test code works locally, uploading my configured test code (for Appium TestNG it's as a .zip file) doesn't seem to run properly, and even though my code calls for a snapshot, snapshots/screenshots don't appear in the AWS device farm runs. 
I've configured my pom.xml file according to the specifications of the AWS Appium TestNG set-up but still the logs for my code don't appear.
So my question is this: is there a way to possible configure both my code and AWS device farm to function correctly with my code so that AWS takes screenshots of the app as the code is executing? And also is there a way to verify whether or not my code is actually running?
Thanks,
Ilian

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with jdk version 8?
If yes then downgrade it to version 7 because for now device farm doesn't work with jdk 8.
And check locally if your appium logs is displaying correct version after downgrading to jdk 7.